# How to get keyCode at OnSelect event of Jquery DatePicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events

Basically I want to stop the date selection when the user presses the enter key

```
inputbox.datepicker({ onSelect: function (date, detail) {
if (detail.lastVal != '') {
if(KeyCode===13) return; // where do i get KeyCode Here
this.value = fromdate + ' to ' + date;
}
else {
fromdate = this.value;
}
},
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
```

I want to pick two date in same input box and my input box also do search if i press enter key.

```
inputbox.on('keyup', function (e) {
if(e.keyCode===13){DoSearch();}
};
```

Comment: explain clearly.what did u try?how did you try? and put some code so that we can help you

Comment: Give us a code sample, and tell us what have you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Top link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/capture-return-enter-key-in-datepicker) in the obvious [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20datapicker%20enter)

```
$('#myDate').datepicker().keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.which === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: I thought it was a lmgtfy link and realised SO doesn't permit it